When using M062x is it preferable to introduce the dispersion correction explicitly or not?
The London dispersion forces are analogous to the interactions observed at long range. From the computational perspective, these dispersion forces can be modeled by directly incorporating any dispersion correction proposed by Grimme and colleagues. (Paper 1). Conversely, some researchers have posited that the M062X density functional incorporates dispersion correction. However, an examination of Truhlar's paper reveals that the parameters of this functional account solely for middle-range interactions (Paper 2).
The question thus arises as to whether, when modelling a system with M062X and introducing dispersion corrections, it is preferable to introduce the dispersion correction explicitly or not?
Furthermore, what are the reasons for either option?

Despite personal misgivings about the M06-2X functional, I would say:
Semi-empirical dispersion corrections are usually created quasi-analytically, and designed to capture all of the long range correlations in your system.
Different XC-functionals capture this different long-range correlation with various degrees of correctness. And then with your SEDC you go and add more, which can lead to double counting issues.
My personal preference would be to consider using the same XC-functional that the creators of the dispersion correction use in their paper, if I strongly care about van der Waals. Often this is PBE (and some corrction schemes are parameterised for multiple funcionals), but Johnson prefers the B86b functional for her XDM stuff, as that comes with minimal extra long range correlations.
Accordingly, I would suggest caution in combining your M06-2X functional with an SEDC... firstly, double check if it has explicit parameters for use in that scheme. If not, I would avoid like the plague unless you really want to parameterise for M06-2X yourself. If it does, those existing parameters should be reasonable-ish.
